# Codeigniter , code execution stops at $this->load->model('recommendations')

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know why my code execution stops at `$this->load->model('recommendations')` . My model class name and file name are same.

Now the page prints `hola1` , but it doesn't print `hola2` and when I used this inside a `try catch block` , still nothing happens and the result is same.

```
echo "hola1";
echo $this->load->model('recommendations');
echo "hola2";
```

**Edit**

After setting my `log_threshold` to `5` in my `config.php` file . I get the following logs.

```
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-11-20 04:39:26 --> Model Class Initialized
```

Comment: Usually the first letter of model class name would be in Upper case. Check your model class name.

Comment: have you checked the code written in model,seems issue in model file

Comment: The file name , class name , and the code above , all have the same name and are lower case

Comment: btw where do you call this? in library?

Comment: I am calling this from a controller functions

Comment: @HarshalMahajan checked it , my model class was implementing `JSONSerializable` even removed that , but still it doesn't work\

Comment: @Mj1992 try edit your `config/system.php` look for log_threshold set it to 5 and set also the log path. See if you can get an accurate of error for your situation

Comment: @Mj1992 then everything is ok , your `recommendations_model.php` is in `app/models/` ? are you loading it in the correct controller? last is try $this->load->model('Recommendations_model'); , is your model class name `Recommendations_model` and last thing how about putting it in autoload see if it will work

Comment: set your error threshhold to ERROR_ALL so you can see what it's complaining about

Comment: In the `commented lines` it says to set threshold to `4` for `All messages` , did that and still getting the same result as I've mentioned in my question , the ERROR_ALL does not work .

Answer (score 0):

A little to late, but maybe someone will have the same issue.

In my case the problem was that I forgot to put a semicolon after calling `$this->db->select()` in my model. So maybe you just need to check your code syntax.